# Reducing I/O latency in webservers- does asyncio is needed when using select in python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

It is well-known that most web-server are I/O bounded programs, waiting for sockets to be read/write-ready before recv/send commands.

Now, I am writing a python web-server program. It uses `select` function to poll whatever the sockets are read/write-ready, and thus forcing `send` and `recv` to be non-blocking, thus reducing significantly the I/O latency of using these commands.

In such case- does using asyncio reduces further the I/O latency? Or it only reduces the CPU usage (which can help only in CPU-bounded programs)?

Comment: They're probably going to be marginally different in speed depending on the backend-task per webrequest. But because asyncio can let heavy/long-running requests be running on the side that will give your users a perceived speedy experience. Where as select won't handle the next request until the previous is done. (long story short, there's more to it and this is a pretty complex question you're asking. It all depends on your implementation, use case, server, etc etc etc)

Comment: If the backend-task per webrequest is high- is it consider to be CPU bounded-program?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `CPU bounded-program`.

Comment: A program that does not waits for an IO (as recv and send) to be completed, i.e., most of its CPU time it uses arithmetic and logical operations, which makes the program to be CPU intensive.

Comment: select is a 'manual' approach for an asycnhronous solution.
Basically you code everything manually.

Asyncio is a higher level approach for implementation of an asynchronous application
.  and can has a lot of features, that can help you to write asynchronous web servers.

It will probably not directly use select, but depending on it's event loop and its related selectors  ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors ) (KqueueSelector, EpollSelector…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need asyncio when using select()

Normally you either write an application with select() or you use asyncio.

Using select is a 'manual' approach for an asynchronous solution.
Basically you code everything by hand and you perform the dispatching with if statements / lookup tables.

Asyncio is a higher level approach for implementation of an asynchronous application and has a lot of features, that can help you to write asynchronous web servers or other servers.

Asyncio would probably not directly use select(), but depending on it's event loop and its related selectors  ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors ) KqueueSelector, EpollSelector…

I think coding will be easier with asyncio, however you have to learn it or at least one framweork, that is based on asyncio.

The coding style is rather different and you have to get used to.
Results should be better and you'll have many libraries for abstraction of common tasks.